# Power Bi Rank function incorrect parameter type

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following summarized table:

```
Store-Employee Transactions =
SUMMARIZE (
    'Transactions',
    'Transactions'[StoreId],
    'Transactions'[employeeId],
    "TransactionCounts", COUNT ( 'Transactions'[transactionId] )
)
```

Now, I'm trying to rank the employees by Transaction Counts in descending order and partition by Store.

```
EmployeeRanking = Rank(SKIP, ORDERBY([TransactionCounts], DESC), PARTITIONBY([StoreId]))
```

Power BI had underlined order by and says "Parameter is not the correct type".

Comment: Somehow, the above worked after I restarted power bi